# Javascript getElementBy

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem to detect the option selection where instead of using getElementById i want to use getElementByValue.Does it exist??
this is my code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var total;


function oneway(){

document.getElementById("return_date").style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("return_time").style.visibility = "hidden";

}

function return_way(){

document.getElementById("return_date").style.visibility = "visible";

document.getElementById("return_time").style.visibility = "visible";

}

function state_price(){
var way=document.getElementById("direction").value;

var placefrom = document.getElementById("state_from").value;
var placeto   = document.getElementById("state_to").value;

if (direction == "oneway"){
    if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="Alor Setar") ||(placefrom =="Alor Setar" && placeto=="Batu Pahat")){

        total=55.00;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total;


    }else if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="Bachok")||(placefrom=="Bachok" && placeto=="Batu Pahat"))
    {

        total=60.00;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total; 


    }else if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="A Famosa") || (placefrom=="A Famosa" && placeto=="Batu Pahat"))
    {

        total=65.50;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total;

    }else if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="Bahau")||(placefrom=="Bahau" && placeto=="Batu Pahat"))
    {
        total=70.00;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total;

    }else if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="Bentong") ||(placefrom=="Bentong" && placeto=="Batu Pahat"))
    {
        total=75.50;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total;
    }else if ((placefrom=="Batu Pahat" && placeto=="Kubang Kerian") ||(placefrom=="Kubang Kerian" && placeto=="Batu Pahat"))
    {
        total=80.00;
        document.booking.total_price.value = total;

    }

    else
    {

        document.booking.txttotal.value = "Fail";
        window.alert("Please enter a different destination");

    }
}
else
{



///something else

}
}
</script>
```

and this is the part of my html coding

```
 <tr > 
 <td>Travel Direction:</td>
 <td >

 <input type="radio" name ="direction" value = "oneway"  onclick = "oneway()"/>One Way
 <input type="radio" name ="direction" value = "return"  onclick = "return_way()"/>Return

 </td>
 </tr>
```

i don't want to use the name as i'm using it in my php coding.so i don;t want to use it.Is there any way where i can do my javascript as i mentioned above (getElementByValue)?Thank You in advance

Comment: Sorry, but I just see "name" property in input type. Where is "id"? Without "id" (sure) won't work it.

Comment: @ben336 i have tried to search...i'm just not sure as i'm a newbie in javascript

Comment: @ViniciusLima i have tried ` <tr > 
<td>Travel Direction:</td>
<td >

<input type="radio" name ="direction" value = "oneway" id = "oneway" onclick = "oneway()"/>One Way
<input type="radio" name ="direction" value = "return" id = "return" onclick = "return_way()"/>Return

</td>
</tr>` i still can use it for my if else statement

Comment: tq @ViniciusLima .i've tried and it worked

Comment: Great Satia!! =) The "id" it was absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can't set the id attribute you can apply a CSS class and use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) (needs IE 9.0 or higher)

Or you can just traverse the whole DOM checking for the value attribute. But this would be slow as hell and very bug-prone without using jQuery or similar.

Edit:
Quentin answer is better, document.querySelector works on IE8 or higher and you don't need to create CSS classes.

Answer (score 7):

> i want to use getElementByValue. Does it exist??

No. You could write your own (looping over all the elements in the document and testing them) or, if you care about initial value, rather than current value, you could use [`querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) with an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Since you are using radio buttons, which don't change values (only checked status) under normal circumstances, that should work fine.

```
document.querySelector('input[value=oneway]');
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem here is you are using getElementById and you are using the name, that is not going to work.

Personally I would check to see if the first radio button [one way] is checked.

```
var isOneWay = document.forms[0].direction[0].checked;
```

Than in the if statement, you can use the Boolean value to determine the logic.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery it has a value selector, ex: $('input["value=your-value"]')